# MySQL rows matched: 1 changed: 0 warnings: 0 for date column

Tags: mysql

Similar questions have been asked but I can't seem to find a solution for my particular problem.

Trying to update "end_date" column in Student table but I receive matched: 1 changed: 0 warnings: 0 as message.

Here's exactly what I did.

```
mysql> SELECT studentID,end_date FROM Student WHERE studentID = 256;
+-----------+----------+
| studentID | end_date |
+-----------+----------+
|       256 | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE Student Set end_date = '2017-12-22' WHERE studentID = 256;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT studentID,end_date FROM Student WHERE studentID = 256;
+-----------+----------+
| studentID | end_date |
+-----------+----------+
|       256 | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

trying to change end_date to '2017-12-22'. The values of end_date column from the select query compared to the update query are clearly different so I'm not sure what is going on. To double check I ran the select query again after the update query. Strangely I can change physical_date and start_date just fine with a similar update statement.

Here is some more context on my Student Table using SHOW CREATE TABLE query.

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `studentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` date NOT NULL,
  `age` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `physical_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'active\ninactive',
  `room` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `auth_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'C\nS\nO',
  `tuition_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'full\npart',
  `email` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `allow_picture` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'yes\nno',
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentID`),
  KEY `fk_Student_Room_idx` (`room`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=262 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: `The old and new results are clearly different` not to me, what "old" and what "new" result are you referring to? I see only 2 identical results where the end_date is NULL in both..... so no difference at all

Comment: Sorry will update question to make it more clear. I was referring to the update query in the middle of the two select queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm really sorry but it looks like there was a before update trigger that changed the end_date to NULL. Hitting myself in the head for not checking everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the back-tics on the column name

i.e.

```
UPDATE Student SET `end_date`="2017-12-22" WHERE studentID=256;
```

Comment: What's your autocommit setting?  Are you accidentally implicitly in a transaction?